# My directive uses isolate scope, but still fetches data from the controller's scope

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have created two directives, one with the controller passed in, and the other with the require passed it.

What I am trying to do it to just check how directives use isolated scopes and utilize the data of its own scope.

But my out put is strange.

Please follow the code below,

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="MyApp">
<head>
    <title>Recipe 02 example 01</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="D:\Rahul Shivsharan\JavaScript-Framework\AngularJS\angular.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="D:\Rahul Shivsharan\JavaScript-Framework\jQuery\jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="D:\Rahul Shivsharan\JavaScript-Framework\BootstrapCSS\bootstrap-3.2.0-dist\js\bootstrap.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="D:\Rahul Shivsharan\JavaScript-Framework\BootstrapCSS\bootstrap-3.2.0-dist\css\bootstrap.css"></link>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="D:\Rahul Shivsharan\JavaScript-Framework\BootstrapCSS\bootstrap-3.2.0-dist\css\bootstrap-theme.css"></link>
    <script type="text/javaScript">
        angular.module("MyApp",[]);
        (function(){
            angular.module("MyApp").controller("myCtrl",myCtrl);
            angular.module("MyApp").controller("StudentCtrl",StudentCtrl);
            angular.module("MyApp").directive("parentClass",parentClass);
            angular.module("MyApp").directive("childClass",childClass);

            function parentClass(){
                var obj = {     
                    restrict : 'EA',
                    controller : "StudentCtrl" 
                }

                return obj;
            };

            function childClass(){
                var obj = {
                    restrict : 'EA',
                    require : "^parentClass",
                    scope : {
                        array : '='
                    },  
                    template : "<ol><li ng-repeat='student in array'>{{student}}</li></ol>",
                    link : function(scope,element,attrs,someCtrl){                      

                    }
                }

                return obj;
            }

            function myCtrl($scope){                    
                $scope.studentList = ["Tom Cruise","Jammy Watson","Simon Colins"]                   
            };

            function StudentCtrl($scope){
                $scope.studentList = ["Shahrukh Khan","Salmaan Khan","Amir Khan"]

            };

        })();
    </script>
</head>
<body ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <parent-class>
        <child-class array="studentList"></child-class>
    </parent-class>
    <pre />
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="student in studentList">{{student}}</li>
    </ul>
</body>
```

In the above code there are two directives 'parentClass' and 'childClass'.
'childClass' directive requires 'parentClass' as its parent directive, and hence 'childClass' uses the controller 'StudentCtrl'

What I am expecting in the output is

the directive 'child-class' should print the students in 'StudentCtrl' and the student outside the directives should be from 'myCtrl',

but what I am getting is both the students are from controller 'StudentCtrl',

When I do the code change in directive 'parentClass' as follows,

```
    function parentClass(){
                var obj = {     
                    restrict : 'EA',
                    controller : "StudentCtrl" ,                        
                    scope : {
                        array : '='
                    }
                }

                return obj;
            };
```

The output is all the students are from controller 'myCtrl' irrespective of the directives closing tag.

The links for the live demonstration is as follows

[Link One](http://jsfiddle.net/rahulshivsharan/8xbr3xfd/9/)

[Link Two](http://jsfiddle.net/rahulshivsharan/bb1jaxyz/3/)

What I am expecting is 
the directive 'child-class' should output list of students present in controller 'StudentCtrl' and the student outside the directives should output from controller 'myCtrl'

Please solve my confusion in scopes also.

Thanks

Comment: you need this http://jsfiddle.net/L0osn87g/ ?

Comment: No, I need to print both the students present in StudentCtrl and myCtrl.  the directive 'child-class' should print students from controller 'StudentCtrl' and after the closing tag of directive 'parent-class' should print students from controller 'myCtrl'. Please give me the solution and explain me as well

Comment: isolate scope applies to the template of the directive, not to the contents of its hosting element

Comment: Ok, so how will I get the disired output. Please suggest me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `parentClass` directive, you do not specify a `scope` value. This means it defaults to `false`.

A false scope value means that the directive does not create a new scope, meaning it will use the scope that is closest (up the scope chain) to it.

In this particular case, the directive uses the scope of the `myCtrl` controller. As such, when you specify the `controller: 'StudentCtrl'`, and inject the `$scope` object to set the `studentList` variable, you overwrite the value in the `myCtrl` controller - thereby giving you the unexpected results.

One way to resolve this is to put `scope: true` as an option to the `parentClass` directive, thereby forcing the directive to create a new scope and not overwrite its parent.